# eval() method, with a variable in jQuery syntax, is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval

I am trying to run a calculator with smallest possible JavaScript code bits. I am using jQuery to further minimize my script section.
But my `eval()` method is not working though `alert(executed)` present just next to it is working fine! What wrong am I doing? Take a look at what I've tried so far!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="wclassth=device-wclassth, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    .inp {
      font-weight: bolder;
      font-size: 5vw;
      width: 13vw;
      height: 13vw;
      margin-bottom: 2vw;
      margin-top: 2vw;
    }
    
    input:hover {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    Answer will be shown here:
  </p>
  <br></br><br></br>
  <table style="background:black; padding:2vw; width:60vw; margin-left:20vw;">
    <th>
      <div id="display" style="width:56vw; height:15vw; background:skyblue; font-weight:bolder; font-size:5vw; color:red;"></div>
    </th>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="1" />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="2" />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="3" />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="+" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="4" />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="5" />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="6" />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="-" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="7" />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="8" />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="9" />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="*" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="." />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="0" />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="/" />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="ans" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("input.inp").on("click", function() {
        if ($(this).val() != "ans") {
          var solve = $("#display").append($(this).val());
        }
        if ($(this).val() == "ans") {
          var result = eval(solve);
          $("p").html(eval(result));
          alert("executed");
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

> Edit: There were some syntax error in this code, which I hope is now fixed.

Comment: `TypeError: solv.val is not a function`

Comment: `solv` is a number (actually, technically `NaN`, which is Not a Number)

Comment: `$("#display").append()` returns `$("#display")` so will not be a number for parseInt to parse - your parseInt should be around `solv.val()`

Comment: Just click on the "Run code snippet" button and observe to see if the errors are fixed. You can also click on the "Run" button in the snippet editor.

Comment: javascript functions should really only be using id's from HTML and css should use classes only for styling. Look at using Divs too instead of tables :) Good luck.

Comment: Recently edited to fix JavaScript error, now there are no messages popping out from console log.

Comment: If you read my question carefully, you will notice I'm talking about minimizing JavaScript as much as possible to run calculator, that can not be possible with one id associated with all the input buttons with different values, so I decided to go with `class` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get value of your `#display` and then pass the same to your `eval` function to get required answer.

**Demo Code** :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="wclassth=device-wclassth, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    .inp {
      font-weight: bolder;
      font-size: 5vw;
      width: 13vw;
      height: 13vw;
      margin-bottom: 2vw;
      margin-top: 2vw;
    }
    
    input:hover {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>

  <p>
    Answer will be shown here: <span></span>
  </p>
  <br></br><br></br>
  <table style="background:black; padding:2vw; wclassth:60vw; margin-left:20vw;">
    <th>
      <div id="display" style="wclassth:56vw; height:15vw; background:skyblue; font-weight:bolder; font-size:5vw; color:red;"></div>
    </th>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="1" />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="2" />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="3" />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="+" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="4" />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="5" />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="6" />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="-" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="7" />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="8" />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="9" />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="*" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="." />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="0" />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="/" />
        <input class="inp" type="button" value="ans" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("input.inp").on("click", function() {

        if ($(this).val() != "ans") {
     $("#display").append($(this).val());//append new value
         
        }
        if ($(this).val() == "ans") {
       var solve = $("#display").text();//get value from display
          var result = eval(solve);//eval
          console.log(result)
          $("span").html(result);
          alert("executed");
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Dear [Swati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10606400/swati) , thanks a lot, now I know what was wrong with my idea!

Answer (score 1):

The `parseInt()` line `parseInt($("#display").append($(this).val());`
will not return what you think it will return, `parseInt()` will try to parse the result of `.append()` which is not a numeric  value, this is how I think you can implement it:

**Also a security note, please try to avoid using [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), please check this**:
[Never use eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!)

```js
$(function () {
  $("input.inp").on("click", function () {
    let solv = $(this).val();
    if (solv != "ans") {    
      $("#display").append(solv);
    }

    if (solv == "ans") {
      let solve = $("#display").text();
      const result = calculateResult(solve);
      $("#ans").html(result);
    }
  });
});

function calculateResult(js) {
  return Function('"use strict";return (' + js + ")")();
}
```

```css
.inp {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 5vw;
  width: 13vw;
  height: 13vw;
  margin-bottom: 2vw;
  margin-top: 2vw;
}
input:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="wclassth=device-wclassth, initial-scale=1.0" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            Answer will be shown here: <span id='ans'></span>
        </p>
        <table style="background: black; padding: 2vw; wclassth: 60vw; margin-left: 20vw;">
            <th><div id="display" style="wclassth: 56vw; height: 15vw; background: skyblue; font-weight: bolder; font-size: 5vw; color: red;"></div></th>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class="inp" type="button" value="1" />
                    <input class="inp" type="button" value="2" />
                    <input class="inp" type="button" value="3" />
                    <input class="inp" type="button" value="+" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class="inp" type="button" value="4" />
                    <input class="inp" type="button" value="5" />
                    <input class="inp" type="button" value="6" />
                    <input class="inp" type="button" value="-" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class="inp" type="button" value="7" />
                    <input class="inp" type="button" value="8" />
                    <input class="inp" type="button" value="9" />
                    <input class="inp" type="button" value="*" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class="inp" type="button" value="." />
                    <input class="inp" type="button" value="0" />
                    <input class="inp" type="button" value="/" />
                    <input class="inp" type="button" value="ans" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer is detailed and spot on, thanks a lot for your help and making me realise my mistakes!